# force size of thumbnail to stay the same but only alter the profile image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay so here's, the scenario I have a thumbnail that contains an artists profile picture, name and genre. The name is at the top and genre at the bottom. The size of the thumbnail needs to be limited by height as well as width. Width causes the problem as when the name is longer another line is created. This pushes down the other elements making the whole thumbnail longer. I do not want to limit the length that the artist can enter in the name so need a solution in css hopefully.

I need the whole thumbnail to be set at a fixed height but the image needs to be shortened to compensate for the extra line(s) in the name. At the moment if there is an extra line the whole thumbnail is made that extra line longer. I need the image to shorten if there is another line in the name or in other words if the content exceeds the containers width.

I hope there is a way to do this and I will provide css and markup if asked for but I don't see how it could help in this scenario. I have included this in the jquery topic as well as i'm not sure if this can just be done with css.

The thumbnail I have included is the one that is causing problems. It is not doing so on jsfiddle but it is on the dev site. Here is the jsfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/6gmRG/ . I have also included the markup and css in this question.

Okay here is the markup for one of the thumbnails. I have removed the links etc for easy reading:

```
<div id="thumbnailwrapper">

 <!--link here-->

 <a href="">

  <!--name here-->

   <b>The Birdman Rallies</b><br>

    <div id="artiststhumbnail">

     <!--image here-->

      <img src="http://newbornsounds.coffeecup.com/artistspictures/The%20Birdman%20Rallies/lamps.jpg" height="100%" alt="The Birdman Rallies" border="0" >
     </div>

     <div id="genre">Electro/acoustic blend</div></a>

</div>
```

Here is the css for the thumbnail and I have removed transitions and box shadow effect for easy reading:

```
#thumbnailwrapper {
width:137px; color:#2A2A2A; margin-right:5px; 
border-radius:0.2em; margin-bottom:5px;
background-color:#E9F7FE; padding:5px;
border-color:#DADADA; border-style:solid;
border-width:thin; font-size:15px
}

#artiststhumbnail {
width:133px; height:130px;
text-align:center;overflow:hidden;
border-color:#DADADA;
border-style:solid; border-width:thin; 
background-color:white; display:inline-block;
}

#genre {
font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;
color:#2A2A2A
 }
```

Comment: Check out this webkit [**DEMO**](http://www.zurb.com/playground/sliding-vinyl) (Chrome/Safari) that might be useful.

Comment: that is quite cool but not what i'm looking for at the moment. Will probabaly use it though

Comment: can you post the markup and css so i can look at at making a solution?  my thought is the whole artist profile div will have a fixed height. inside of the profile div will be name, picture, genre. i would put the name and genre text in a span. then i would use jquery to look at the height of the name span and use that to determine if there is a second line. if the height is a name with 2 lines, i would then set the profile pic height rule to subtract x so we can account for the extra line.

Comment: @JacobWindsor, If your thumbnails can not handle an artists name, your thumbnails are too small to begin with. Maybe use a jQuery To auto-scroll the artist name in a loop. I agree with chirsvillanueva that looking at your markup is needed. jsFiddle if possible. Also, as the non-related DEMO above shows, the artist name is longer than the thumbnails width.

Comment: @chrisvillanueva these were my original thoughts. I will post the markup and add your suggestions in jsfiddle tomorrow. Could you help me with jquery as I have no idea thanks.  Most artist names are handled it is just some with particuarly long names. Any larger thumbnails wouldn't look right. As I said I will post the markup and CSS tomorrow as its rather late in england

Comment: @arttronics just thought id add auto scrolling is something I try to avoid. The site takes on a very simple clean, google style  design so it would not look right to have automatic animations going on

Comment: @JacobWindsor. sure, post whatever you have tomorrow.  i'll take a look and see if i can help.  i only request markup+styles since designers are very particular about things.  so, it doesn't help to come up with a pure js-solution that would detract from a style.  thx

Comment: @chrisvillanueva I have added the markup, css and jsfiddle. Please have a look. I am not asking him to code for me just helping me along in the right direction. I do have an understanding of jquery but need to know what kind of thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, here is a quick demo.  you can see my fiddle code here: http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/TdLq4/1/

it's only meant as a technique/guide.  it's not production-ready, of course.

here's my thinking behind the approach.  i nested the artist name within a span.  i then used jquery to get the span height for each artist name within a given thumbnail wrapper.  i then used the height value to determine if there were two lines for an artist name.  i used 20 as my magic number to signify two-line text.  you'll have to come up with your own dynamic test value.  anyway, once i determine a span has two-lines, i then adjust the height of the .artiststhumbnail sibling.  i'm then able to define a static height for .artiststhumbnail so it aligns with the other thumbnail wrappers.

this should get you going to make progress on your requirement.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Works like a charm. This is the kind of thing I had in mind but don't know enough jquery to execute it.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but it doesn't seem to be working in ie. Any ideas why?

Comment: Don't worry it's fine. I forgot to put the console.log back into a comment. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your img tag. you have defined there height 100%.
That is why it resizes.

try adding

```
#artistthumbnail img {
width:130px;
height:133px;
}
```

and see what that does.

Comment: The problem is not the height 100% as that needs to be so in the markup. If you look at the css the height is set to 130px the 100% just makes it fill the height of the container. The width can be anything but has a max of 133px.

Comment: You have set dimensions on the wrapper div. not the img element. Any resize issues can come from there. Also you can use max-width/height values in css.